# Java socket programming - requests

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a messaging application in java using sockets and currently the server will wait for a request and just automatically accept it:

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(1254);
Socket s1 = s.accept();
```

If there any way in which I can detect requests to the server and allow the server to only accept certain requests?

Comment: How would you want to distinguish one request from another? Originating IP?

Comment: Not before you accept it. So accept it then filtrer it (based on your condition). Passing the `Socket` to a distinct `Thread` to let the `ServerSocket` accept the next one is better too.

Comment: It depends on your criteria.

Comment: servlet filters, for example

Comment: a socket is a low level object. Unless you are working with devices that can't support http, I would go other routes

Comment: @AxelH No. `Servlet` is a Java Servlet Specification class, which is *part* of the J2EE specification, but widely available without it. Tomcat is a case in point.

Comment: @AxelH I had already given you a lead. Tomcat. It is a servlet container, not an application servier. The `servlet-api.jar` file you need to compile a Servlet is provided with Tomcat. You do not need any part of J2EE for that. And it will run on Tomcat, of course, which, again, is not an application server. This is all rather basic.

Comment: @AxelH The difference between Servlet container and Application Server is that a Servlet container has no EJB, no JMS, no JTA, no EAR files, no Persistence layer, .... Quite considerable, and certainly not just 'semantic'. I confirm that a `ServletFilter` works with a `Servlet`. I don't know why this is considered surprising, or indeed why you keep banging on about all this at all.

Comment: @AxelH You are the one who said, and I quote, 'Servlet is a JEE class, not Socket, this is Java SE'. We are waiting for you to acknowledge this error, instead of arguing about it, dismissing it as 'semantics', making basic errors about what Tomcat does and doesn't do, etc. Any time you want to *actually* remove those comments, instead of just *saying* you will and doing exactly nothing about it for another three hours, feel free. Too much talk and not enough action here.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me what you mean with "certain requests", however you can accept it, validate it and if it is not a "certain request" you simply drop the connection.

Comment: this answer should have been a comment mate

Comment: @nafas Why? It provides a solution, and a solution that is also provided in another answer that you haven't commented on.

Comment: @iehrlich It does provide a solution: "you can accept it, validate it and if it is not a "certain request" you simply drop the connection."

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way that you can deny request without accepting it, (until and unless you have some reverse proxy setup like nginx).

After accepting the socket you can check out the various parameters for example Socket's remote address (check for more info `java.net.Socket`), and close the socket if you don't want the connection to be established.

Comment: Just to add some context, if the idea is to secure your process to prevent an overflood by robot, you can always add some rules to your firewall to only accept some IP range, based on the application of this socket of course

Comment: @AxelH (+1) thanks for your comment but for that point only I edited my answer and added 'until and unless you have some reverse proxy setup like nginx,`  and off course firewall can be one more option from so many others available....